# Using/enabling gsettings/dconf key without running gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: mate-desktop

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Linx Mint MATE edition, installed on a laptop with a 4K 15.6 inch display. The high dpi means that most UI's have to be scaled. I have gotten most of the programs I use daily to scale nicely, except for Sublime Text (3).

It is possible to enable "high dpi" mode in Sublime Text 3 by setting the gsettings/dconf key `org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor` to something larger than 1 (2 works great for me), for example with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 2.0
```

The problem is that, for this to have an effect, I have to have `gnome-settings-daemon` running. The MATE desktop environment (which is a fork of the no-unmaintained GNOME 2) uses it's own settings daemon (`mate-settings-daemon`), and it is not possible to run both this and `gnome-settings-daemon` at the same time. When I try starting `gnome-settings-daemon` with `mate-settings-daemon` already running, I get the following error (among others):

```
** (gnome-settings-daemon:4051): WARNING **: You can only run one xsettings manager at a time; exiting
```

I would prefer to keep using the MATE desktop.

Does anyone know of a way around this? Or a different way of enabling high dpi support in Sublime Text 3, without having gnome-settings-daemon running?

Comment: Did you try putting stuff in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`? I have `[Settings]
gtk-cursor-blink = false`, which works when gsd-xsettings is not running.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

`"dpi_scale": 2.0`

Comment: I just edited this reply, thinking it was *my* reply. Sorry for the judgemental comment in my edit note! (I wish there was a PM function in cases like these).